# Ubuntu 22.04 won't recognize second monitor/TV

Tags: multiple-monitors

My hardware:
RaspberryPi4 8Gb RAM
Main display monitor ACER + Secondary display SonyTV.

6 months ago I have Ubuntu 21.04 on a 32Gb microSD. Both displays working fine automatically recognized by OS.
Recently upgraded the microSD for a faster 128Gb. Decided to make a fresh install with Ubuntu 22.04. OS does not recognize SonyTV as secondary display.

Rainbow splash appears in both screens during boot. After OS loads SonyTV signal disappears.

If I disconnect the ACER monitor the OS boots up using SonyTV as main screen so I assume all hardware is OK and thus the problem is in the OS.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you look into Settings > Display and check if the second display appears on the list? You may have to select Join Displays in the Display settings. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-dual-monitors.html.en

Comment: Settings -> Display TV does not appear on the list, only the monitor.